# Issue configuring APC

Tags: php, nginx, apc, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to configure APC but it doesn't seem to take my changes.
I an on ubuntu server 12.10
I use nginx and php-fpm.

All my changes are in this file: /etc/php5/mods-available/apc.ini

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=1G
apc.ttl=3600
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.max_file_size=1M
apc.stat=0
```

And yes I restarted nginx.
When I check apc.php, my changes are not displayed....just the defaults.
Any clue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restart your PHP-FPM.
If you're having it in your init.d, try:

$ service php-fpm restart

And check if you're using the correct ini file, by checking "Loaded Configuration File" and "Additional .ini files parsed" of your phpinfo(); output;

Comment: You are right, I'm new to php fpm, I haven't thought of it as a service. Weird but working really well. Thank you very much.